# laravel 5.8 - postman test api request become empty

Tags: php, laravel

I follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876) and use `postman` to test the `api`. Everything works as expected in `localhost`. but when I upload to the production server, somehow the `api` request data is filtered out.

I follow the instruction to install `passport`, and all that settings in various files. then I `php artisan migrate` at the production server, after that `php artisan passport:install`, then the message said successfully:

```
Encryption keys generated successfully.
Personal access client created successfully.
Client ID: 1
Client secret: <some long strings>
Password grant client created successfully.
Client ID: 2
Client secret: <some long strings>
```

I have a test function:

```
ResidentsController.php:

public function testing(Request $request){
        return $request->all();
    // return ['test'=>'success'];
    }
```

and route:

```
api.php:
Route::post('/resident/test','ResidentsController@testing');
```

So I am using `postman` to call:

```
POST : http://examplehost/api/resident/test/
```

with data:

```
{"name":"user001"}
```

and header:

```
Content-Type: application/json //<-- which enough for localhost
```

but the data return:

```
[] ///<--- I am expecting {"name":"user001"}
```

and I test with header:

```
[
Content-Type: application/json,
Authorization: {{'bearer'.$accessToken}} ///<-- which the direction from tutorial
]
```

still get back the same:

```
[]
```

I am not sure which part I have miss out. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postman, click on body, select raw and select JSON(application/json) from the dropdown

In the body, insert your JSON

```
 {"name":"user001"}
```

In your testing method

```
if ( $request->isJson() ) {
    $json = json_decode(trim($request->getContent()),true);
    return response()->json($json);
}
```